# Microsoft ServiceBus - The argument entityName is null or empty

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

I am using Servicebus as a link between a web-application and BizTalk.
In the web-application i earlier had the whole endpoint defined in the web.config but the endpoints has to be dynamic so i tried to set the endpoint by code.

After the change i only get an exception when i try to send a message to the queue. (ArgumentException - The argument entityName is null or empty)

Here is the code sending the message to the queue:

```
string queuename = Company.GetQueueName(O.companyId);
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IOrder>("requestQueueClientEndpoint", new EndpointAddress(ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", queuename, string.Empty)));
var OrdRspChannel = factory.CreateChannel();

OrdRspChannel.Order(O);
```

And here is the configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="securityBehavior">
      <TransportClientEndpointBehavior>
        <tokenProvider>
          <sharedSecret issuerName="owner" issuerSecret="SECRET REMOVED" />
          <serviceCertificate>
            <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
          </serviceCertificate>
        </tokenProvider>
      </TransportClientEndpointBehavior>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <netMessagingBinding>
    <binding name="netMessagingBinding" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sessionIdleTimeout="00:10:00" prefetchCount="-1">
      <transportSettings batchFlushInterval="00:00:01" />
    </binding>
  </netMessagingBinding>
</bindings>

<client>
  <!-- Invoke BizTalk via Service Bus Queue -->
  <endpoint address="ADDRESS REMOVED" behaviorConfiguration="securityBehavior" binding="netMessagingBinding" bindingConfiguration="netMessagingBinding" contract="Procurement_MVC3.IOrder" name="requestQueueClientEndpoint" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Here is the StackTrace:

```
{System.ArgumentException: The argument entityName is null or empty.
Parameter name: entityName

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactory.CheckValidEntityName(String entityName, Int32 maxEntityNameLength, Boolean allowSeparator, String paramName)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactory.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginCreateMessageSender>b__1b(AsyncCallback c, Object s)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.OpenOnceManager.OpenOnceManagerAsyncResult`1.BeginOpenCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.OpenOnceManager.OpenOnceManagerAsyncResult`1.BeginOpen()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.OpenOnceManager.OpenOnceManagerAsyncResult`1..ctor(OpenOnceManager openOnceManager, TimeSpan openTimeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Func`3 beginOperation, EndOperation`1 endOperation)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.OpenOnceManager.Begin[T](AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Func`3 beginOperation, Func`2 endOperation)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactory.BeginCreateMessageSender(String entityPath, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ServiceBusOutputChannel.OpenMessagingFactoryAndMessageSenderAsyncResult.CreateFactoryComplete(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ServiceBusOutputChannel.OpenMessagingFactoryAndMessageSenderAsyncResult..ctor(ServiceBusOutputChannel outputChannel, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ServiceBusOutputChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Procurement_MVC3.IOrder.Order(Order Order)
   at Procurement_MVC3.Controllers.HomeController.ViewOrder(String id, Nullable`1 date, Nullable`1 confirmqty, String orderrowid, String supplierorderId, Boolean confirm) in c:\Projects2\trunk\Procurement_MVC3\Procurement_MVC3\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 229}
```

I have searched both Google and StackOverflow for similar scenarios but found nothing.
I also have to update a production-environment with this code and this is the last piece of the puzzle so it's starting to drag on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd628639.aspx) API takes three parameters, protocol, namespace and service path (which, for the binding you're using, maps to the queue name). In the example you provide you're passing the queue name as the namespace, and you're missing the entity name, thus causing the missing entity name exception.

Try switching your snippet to something like the following:

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IOrder>("requestQueueClientEndpoint", new EndpointAddress(ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", namespaceName, queuename)));
```

Comment: I guess i misinterpreted the parameter names.
I find it odd that it took 22 days before somebody found the solution.
Thanks a lot for the answer however!
I will mark this as the solution when i get a chance to test it!